# efficient and fast function calling on 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, numpy

I have a 2d numpy object array : `A` and a numpy array of values : `l` (nx2 array)

Every element in the 2d numpy object array has two values like [ax1, ay1] and similarly for `l`.

Im calling my own distance function and calculating the distance between the first element of l with every element in A and then taking the minimum distance. The loop looks like this:

```
for r in range(A.shape[0]):
    for s in range(A.shape[1]):
        lencent = l.shape[0]
        dist = []
        for p in range(lencent):
             dist.append(distancefunction(A[r,s],A[r,s],l[p,0],l[p,1]))
        #print dist
        val = np.min(dist)
        #print val
        tempimg[r,s] = val
```

But this take huge amount of time when the numpy array A is large, or l is large, or both. Is there any pythonic way to optimize the performance of this loop?

Comment: Making this double loop faster using NumPy (if possible) would most likely require seeing the definition of `distancefunction`.

Comment: it is a complex function to calculate W2 distance(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric)

Comment: NumPy object arrays are slower than NumPy float arrays. They could be even slower than Python lists. Python loops are generally slower than equivalent NumPy function calls. In the above you've only used NumPy in one place: `np.min`. To get better performance using NumPy you need to off-load more of the work to NumPy function calls. Since there is not much opportunity to do that in the code you've posted, the only place for possible improvement is to rewrite `distancefunction` to accept `A` and `l` as inputs and to return an *array* of results instead of just one number at a time.

Comment: +1 to unutbu; you can provide distancefunction code, so we can suggest its numpy based computation if possible, or other improvements. IMPOV, this is the only possibility to improve performance.

Comment: As the comments suggest, I would scrap this question and post a new question. Post the `distancefunction` and ask how you can make it optimized for numpy. If it involves array operations (and looking and the def. it certainly might) you'll notice a large speedup.